# Laravel 4 Route Group

Tags: laravel-4

I have two different users and I am trying to group my routes so that other user can not redirect to other user page. Example when I login as a guest, I can redirect to the reports page although only admin can view the reports page.
I did the following, but now, I don't have access to the grouping routes only those outside grouping.
The following is my code:

=>Filters

```
Route::filter('admin', function(){
$user = Auth::user();
if($user->type == "admin"){
     return true;
}
if (Request::ajax()){
    return Response::make('Unauthorized', 404);
}
return View::make('404_auth');
});

Route::filter('guest', function(){
$user = Auth::user();
if($user->type == "guest"){
    return true;
}
if (Request::ajax()){
    return Response::make('Unauthorized', 404);
}
return View::make('404_auth');
});
```

=>Routes

```
Route::get('/', function() {
return View::make('home');
});
Route::get('home', function() {
    return View::make('home');
});
Route::get('login', function() {
    return View::make('login');
});
Route::get('register', function() {
    return View::make('register');
});

Route::post('register', 'HomeController@register');
Route::post('login', 'HomeController@login');
Route::get('logout', 'HomeController@logout');
Route::post('/', 'HomeController@postChangeLanguage');

Route::group(['before' => 'admin'], function() {
Route::get('reports', function() {
    $data = DB::table('application')->get();
    $exam_id = Apply::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->pluck('exam_id');
    $exam = Exam::where('id', $exam_id)->get();

    return View::make('admin/admin_side', compact('data', 'exam'));
});
Route::post('reports', 'AdminController@search');
});

Route::group(['before' => 'guest'], function() {
    Route::get('apply', function() {
        $city = Session::get('city');
        return View::make('apply', compact('city', $city));
    });
    Route::get('location', function() {
        return View::make('location');
    });
    Route::get('completed', function() {
        return View::make('getpdf');
    });
    Route::post('location', 'HomeController@location');
    Route::post('apply', 'HomeController@apply');
    Route::post('completed', 'PdfController@getpdf');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in the filter, you just return the situation you do not want to proceed

=>Filters

```
Route::filter('admin', function(){
    $user = Auth::user();
    if($user->type != "admin"){
        return View::make('404_auth');
    }
    if (Request::ajax()){
        return Response::make('Unauthorized', 404);
    }
});

Route::filter('guest', function(){
    $user = Auth::user();
    if($user->type != "guest"){
        return View::make('404_auth');
    }
    if (Request::ajax()){
        return Response::make('Unauthorized', 404);
    } 
});
```

[laravel 4.2 route doc](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#route-filters).

And if it still not working, please provide more information so everyone can have more ideas to help.